# How to give screenshot file name in xamarin,ui test

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a constructor to wrap around all the test cases to take a screenshot upon failure of the assert. But the screenshot always gives me screenshot-1.png and when the second test is run it overrides the name with that screenshot. won't be able to differentiate screenshot

Code snippet:

```
   public void UITest(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           var Screenshot = App.Screenshot($"Assert Error"+ GetType().Name);

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Test

```
public void MyMethod(){
UITest(() =>
            {
            //logic
            //Assert
             });
}
```

So whenever this is failed test is taking a screenshot but with same file name. how to give a file name as the current test method name?

Comment: where is the code which is generating screenshot-1?

Comment: My quick googling is failing me, but I swear I've read somewhere the name is only applied when running online in AppCenter. Local runs force the naming convention you're seeing. Take a look [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/353627/#Comment_353627) where someone is renaming the screenshot while moving it's location. Might be a possible solution for you.

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
Xamarin.UITest.IApp.ScreenShot(string screenshotname);
```

as mentioned here in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.uitest.iapp.screenshot?view=xamarin-uitest-sdk)

To generate different filename each time append randomly generated.

Comment: This only applies a name to the step in the test results.  It doesn't name the file.